# Run one script from another on php console?

Tags: php, recursion, console

For example I have a simple php script.

**write.php**

```
<?
echo "Hello World!";

if( $argv['1'] == 'twotimes' ) {
  // call write.php again with 'onetime' param (How ??)
} 

echo "Done";

?>
```

If I run `php write.php onetime` on console:
It should print `Hello World!` only once. Print `Done` in the end.

If I run `php write.php twotimes` on console:
It should print `Hello World!` and then call same script again to print another `Hello World!`. Print `Done` in the end.

How to achieve this ?

**Remember:** Calling the same script with different param is my objective.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may use php exec() funcion like this:

```
exec('php write.php myparam');
```

but it seems to me, it's a bad practice.

Comment: Could you please explain why it is a bad practice? Due to memory, permissions or what?